# Does SBCL for lisp handle scope differently? It does not seem to pass scope into called functions?

Tags: scope, lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

When using emacs or my android app I run

```
(defun big (num) (setf num2 5)(little num)))
(defun little (num)(+ num2 num))
```

`Little` happily accepts num2 but when I run it in my SBCL repl (with sublimetext3) it does not.

Is this correct?

What is a workaround without creating a global variable for num2?

I could just pass a second argument `(little num num2)`

But this wont work when I am trying to mapcar `little`  over a list. Because I can only have one argument when mapcaring correct?

Comment: Please copy and paste full interaction: what you give the REPL and what it gives you back. There are too many problems with your code for us to guess which one you are talking about.

Comment: `num2` is an undefined variable. The exact effects using undefined variables is undefined in Common Lisp.

Answer (score 10):

Please read [§6. Variables](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/variables.html) from [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/).

Unlike Emacs Lisp, Common Lisp relies on lexical scope by default (Emacs Lisp is [dynamic by default](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DynamicBindingVsLexicalBinding)). Dynamic scope (i.e. indefinite scope and dynamic extent) is provided by declaring variables *special*, and by convention, they are written with asterisks around their names (named "earmuffs"), like `*standard-output*`. You use [`defparameter` or `defvar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defpar.htm) to declare those variables. Since it has a global effect, you **should never** use them from inside functions; likewise, your usage of `setf` is not defined in Common Lisp: no variable named `num2` was declared previously in the scope; besides, even if it did, using a global/special variable for local variable is bad style.

### Dynamic scope

With special variables, you can for example locally rebind the standard output: the new value is only visible while the code is inside the body of the `let` binding:

```
(let ((*standard-output* *error-output*))
  (print "Stream redirection"))
```

By default, `print` writes to the stream bound to `*standard-output*`; here, the stream is locally bound to the one given by `*error-output*`. As soon as you escape the `let`, `*standard-output*` reverts to its previous value (imagine there is a stack).

### Lexical scope

With lexical scope, your code can only access the bindings that are visible in the text surrounding your code (and the global scope), and the extent is indefinite: it is possible to access a binding (sometimes indirectly) even after the code returns from the `let`:

```
(let ((closure
        (let ((count 0))
          (lambda () (print (incf count))))))
  (funcall closure)
  (funcall closure))

;; prints:
;; 1
;; 2
```

The `lambda` expression creates a closure, which captures the variable named `count`. Every time you call it, it will increase the `count` variable and print it. If you evaluate the same code another time, you define another closure and create another variable, with the same name.

### Mapcar

> Because I can only have one argument when mapcaring correct?

Not exactly; the function called by `mapcar` should be able to accept at least as many elements as the number of *lists* that are given to it (and it should also not require more mandatory arguments):

```
(mapcar (lambda (x y) (* x y))
        '(1 2 3)
        '(0 3 6))
=> (0 6 18)

(mapcar #'list '(1 2) '(a b) '(+ /))
=> ((1 a +) (2 b /))
```

The function can also be a closure, and can use special variables.

#### ... with a closure

```
(defun adder (x)
  (lambda (y) (+ x y)))

(mapcar (adder 10) '(0 1 2))

=> (10 11 12)
```

The `adder` functions takes a number `x` and returns a closure which accepts a number `y` and returns `(+ x y)`.

#### ... with a special variable

If you prefer dynamic scope, use earmuffs and give it a meaningful name:

```
(defparameter *default-offset* 0)
```

... and define:

```
(defun offset (x)
  (+ x *default-offset*))
```

You can then `mapcar` too:

```
(let ((*default-offset* 20))
  (mapcar #'offset '(1 2 3)))

=> (21 22 23)
```

---

As said by jkiiski in comments, you can also declare special variables with  `(declare (special ...))` where you usually put declarations (when entering a `let`, a `defun`, ...). You could also use the special operator [`progv`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_progv.htm). This can be useful to have "invisible" variables that are only known by a set of functions to exchange information. You rarely need them.

Comment: You can also declare a variable to be special inside a function if you want dynamic scope with no global variable, but that's rarely done.

Comment: wow this is great info. Its funny that i can get so far into writing a working program without these basic understandings.